# Use Google App Engine to retrieve large file (http GET) and store in Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a use case where I need to retrieve a large file (3-4 GB) from a remote server and store it in Cloud Storage. I know how to write code to allow me to *manually* perform this action, but I would like to automate the process. How do I retrieve the file using urlfetch and persist the result directly to Cloud Storage?

Comment: Have you considered [Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-url-list)?

Comment: Requests using URLFEtch are limited in size by front end requests for traditional appengine.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/outbound-requests#quotas_and_limits  So that's not even an option.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered that after I wrote this post... everything I had retrieved to date was pretty small and so I had mistakenly assumed bigger downloads would be similar.

Comment: @mensi, if you post that as an answer I will approve it, that's the correct way to achieve what I want to do. Please include the link. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it appears I can't use Transfer Service for my needs... I don't have the ability to determine MD5 hashes for the files. Looking for other options...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mensi suggested, the easiest way to do this is to use the [Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-url-list). It won't work for my special case, but for the general case it's the way to go.